# Connect Two Async Calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below JavaScript adds a item to a list and a file to a picture library, both in SharePoint. The add function calls the upload function but I don't want the add function to complete until the upload function is complete. Naturally the upload function takes longer most of the time. What is the best way to do this?

Add item to list:

```
function addNewPunchlistItem() {

var endpointUrl = myURL + "PunchlistTracking/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Punchlist Items')/items";

if ($('#getFile').val()) {
    uploadFile(myFormDigest, '#getFile', $('#itemNumber').val() + "_image.png");
}

call;

var call = $.ajax({
    url: endpointUrl,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "__metadata": { type: "SP.Data.Punchlist_x0020_ItemsListItem" },
        Title: $('#itemShortDesc').val(),
        FSEId: $('#itemFSE').val(),
        PunchlistNumber: $('#itemNumber').val(),
        Open: $('#itemOpenDate').val(),
        Type: $('#itemType').val(),
        ResponsibleId: $('#itemResponsible').val(),
        LongDescription: $('#itemLongDesc').val(),
        ItemImage: { Description: "", Url: myURL + "PunchlistTracking/Lists/PicturesList/" + $('#itemNumber').val() + "_image.png" }
    }),
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": myFormDigest
    }
});

call.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    alert('Punchlist item ' + $('#itemNumber').val() + " added successfully.");
    init();
});

call.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('fail');
    var response = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
    var message = response ? response.error.message.value : textStatus;
    console.log(message);
});
}
```

Upload file:

```
function uploadFile(FormDigest, FileInput, fileName) {

var serverRelativeUrlToFolder = 'Lists/Pictures';
var fileInput = jQuery(FileInput);

var serverUrl = myURL + "PunchlistTracking";

var getFile = getFileBuffer();

getFile.done(function (arrayBuffer) {

    var addFile = addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer);
    addFile.fail(onError);
});

getFile.fail(onError);

function getFileBuffer() {
    var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function (e) {
        deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
    }
    reader.onerror = function (e) {
        deferred.reject(e.target.error);
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileInput[0].files[0]);
    return deferred.promise();
}   //  getFileBuffer

function addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer) {

    var fileCollectionEndpoint = String.format(
            "{0}/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/files" +
            "/add(overwrite=true, url='{2}')",
            serverUrl, serverRelativeUrlToFolder, fileName);

    return jQuery.ajax({
        url: fileCollectionEndpoint,
        type: "POST",
        data: arrayBuffer,
        processData: false,
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": FormDigest,
            "content-length": arrayBuffer.byteLength
        }
    });
}   //  addFileToFolder

function onError(error) {
    alert(error.responseText);
}   //  onError

}   //  uploadFile
```

Comment: You can use `promise.all()` if they are not co related and can run in parallel. If not you can promisify the prerequisite async operation first and use `.then` to attach the second one and use the resolution of the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is with Promises, like you are already doing.  Get your *uploadFile* function to return a promise, and in the "then" or "done" of that promise, then make the second call.  Exactly as you are doing with the *getFileBuffer* call and the *addFileToFolder* call